# Kony Mobile Apps to react Native Mobile Apps

Tags: react-native, temenos-quantum

Is there any tool or any strategy for converting Kony Mobile apps to React Native Mobile Apps?

Comment: Just Do Google Before Post On StackOVerflow

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion without giving a thought on it :) Anyone would google first, know already known strategies and then ask. So that could be implicitly understood by you :) @AjayPandya

Comment: i can provide some docs regarding kony native but no idea about react native at the moment, I would suggest you to create kony ticket for this.

Comment: No. There is no tool or strategy to convert between kony and react native. Kony has a customized VM where it's  CUSTOMIZED JavaScript runs.  And react native is entirely different . so , conversion will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can covert Mobile app that is written on Kony - Framework and covert them into React native code. The only possible useful stuff that can be done is..extract the JS based business logic from Kony code and you can covert them into Type Script in React native but that too will help only understanding part and make easy to re-write easy but you have to re-write it.

Meaning you can extract some of the business logic which was part of Kony code base and convert them into Type script to have better understanding when you do re-writing of project into React-native.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

in V8 sp4 latest release you can include react native code into kony and communicate with react native to kony app but you cannot export kony to react native.

Using this feature, you can integrate a React Native app (which is developed in React Native framework) into a Kony app

please read the below article for more information.

https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Content/Integrate_React_Native_App_into_Kony_App.htm